# Edges "twisted" by the subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am learning modeling on Blender and I have some difficulties with the subsurf modifier.

Here is my mesh with the modifier display off :
[image]

And here it is with the display on :
[image]

Some edges are twisted and I don't understand why. 
I tried to :

- removes doubles
- recalc normals
- delete the vertices and make a new one (makes it even worst)

Could someone, please, explain me why it is happening and how can I correct it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like there are vertices in your mesh that are not attached.  See the video below.

[image]

Double check all of the vertices around your twisted area and merge those that aren't connected by press Alt+M on the keyboard.

Comment: Hello @CyberBurst , Thank you for your advice.

It was not my case but it gave me the solution. I deleted the edges and not only the vertex. Simply removing the edges and creating new ones resolved my problem. 

Though I still don't know why it happen.